# Throw Google Chrome alert when a password field is clicked on from Google Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm making my first Google Chrome extension. The purpose of the extension is to store password hints and throw a generic alert asking them to open their extension to see the hint. I want the alert to be shown only when the user is on a login page (Gmail login, Facebook login, Amazon login, etc.) and the password field is selected.

I tried using a content script to achieve this but I have no idea why it is not working or how to achieve this.

Here's what I have so far:

**content.js**

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function (tab) {
    var inputs = document.getElementByTagName('input');
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].getAttribute('type') == 'password') {
            alert("Open extension");
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by its not working?  Are there any errors shown in the console?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Usually, including a *manifest.json*, some of the background *and* content scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in the line where you get all the inputs and assign them to "inputs" variables. You are missing the "s" in "Elements".

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
```